# What's the point of using <b:skin> if I can use <style>? Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

I can't find a good source of information about this. Why would I want to use `<b:skin>`, `<b:section>`, `<b:widget>` if there is a possibility to create a page without that? And what advantage is there of using those?

Also I have to necessarily include one `<b:section>`, but it's possible to leave it empty. Why is this including mandatory then?